# Unity: Game works in full screen but not in windowed, why? (Updated)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

Here's what the game is supposed to do:

[image]

When I build the game and click on the red balls in the window, nothing happens...

Can someone help me, please?

Here is my code for my Camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cam : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speedH = 2f, speedV = 2f;
    private float yaw = 0f, pitch = 0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        yaw += speedH * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        pitch -= speedV * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, yaw, 0f);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the game loop. When the game start there are X balls generated and a countdown timer start. When I hit a ball it's destroyed and another is generated in random positions.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Loop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cam;
    public GameObject target;
    Cam camScript;

    [Range(3, 5)]
    public int maxTarget;

    [Range(-5, 6)]
    public int minPos, maxPos;

    [Range(0, 2)]
    public int difficulty, mode;

    [Range(0, 50)]
    private float timeRemaining;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int timer;
    public float timeAdded, timeRemoved;
    public int timerMultiplier;

    public float points;
    public int touched, missed, click;
    public float accuracy;

    private bool isRunning;

    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        SetDifficulty(difficulty);
        SetMode(mode);

        isRunning = true;
        points = 0;
        touched = 0;
        missed = 0;
        click = 0;
        accuracy = 0;
        timeRemaining = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxTarget; i++)
        {
            GenerateTargets(minPos, maxPos);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && isRunning)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Target")
                {
                    Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);

                    points++;
                    touched++;
                    click++;

                    timeRemaining += timeAdded;

                    GenerateTargets(minPos, maxPos);
                }
                else if (hit.transform.tag == "Back")
                {
                    points -= 0.5f;
                    missed++;
                    click++;

                    timeRemaining -= timeRemoved;
                }
            }
        }

        if (timeRemaining > 0) timeRemaining -= (Time.deltaTime * 2);
        timer = (int)timeRemaining;
        if (timeRemaining <= 0) EndGame();

        if (click != 0) accuracy = (((touched * 100) / click) + (100 - ((missed * 100) / click))) / 2;
    }

    private void GenerateTargets(int min, int max)
    {
        float xPos = Random.Range(min, max);
        float yPos = Random.Range(min, max);

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(xPos, yPos, 0f);

        Instantiate(target, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    private void EndGame()
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    private void SetDifficulty(int difficulty)
    {
        switch (difficulty)
        {
            // Easy
            case 0:
                maxTarget = 5;
                minPos = -1;
                maxPos = 2;
                timeAdded = 2;
                timeRemoved = 0.5f;
                timerMultiplier = 1;
                break;

            // Medium
            case 1:
                maxTarget = 4;
                minPos = -3;
                maxPos = 4;
                timeAdded = 1.5f;
                timeRemoved = 0.75f;
                timerMultiplier = 2;
                break;

            // Hard
            case 2:
                maxTarget = 3;
                minPos = -5;
                maxPos = 6;
                timeAdded = 1f;
                timeRemoved = 1f;
                timerMultiplier = 3;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SetMode(int mode)
    {
        switch (mode)
        {
            // Low Range
            case 0:
                cam.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -20);
                break;

            // Mid Range
            case 1:
                cam.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -30);
                break;

            // Long Range
            case 2:
                cam.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, -50);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it helps but I'm on macOS.

Thanks in advance for the reply !!

Comment: Pretty hard to tell ... In general you should use `hit.tranform.CompareTag` instead of a direct `==` which might silently fail while `CompareTag` makes sure this tag exists and there is no typo (it will throw an exception). I would also add a log when hitting nothing or when none of the tags is a match so you can at least see in your Apps logfile at which point something goes wrong ..

Comment: I tried and I have the same problem my game works perfectly in editor but not when builded. And my Player.log is not generated like it should...